# Presence of link/text in search results pages using selenium webdriver C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver using C# for Automation Testing.

I will try to explain my problem through an example.

I search for a particular term in some search sites say www.google.com and get several pages of results.

Now, i am trying to locate the presence of a particular link/Text in Search results by iterating through all the search results pages.

Hope someone can help me through this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Below is some of my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) { 
     IWebDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver(); 
     d1.Navigate().GoToUrl("cocodle.com/";); 
     IWebElement e1 = d1.FindElement(By.Name("q")); 
     e1.SendKeys("Selenium"); 
     IWebElement e2 = d1.FindElement(By.Name("sa")); e2.Submit(); 
}
```

Comment: I am able to open a search page and search for a text "Selenium" and got search results. Now i am trying to locate text link "Web Driver - Do only what matters" which is on fouth page of search results. How can i do that?

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();
d1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.cocodle.com/");
            IWebElement e1 = d1.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            e1.SendKeys("Selenium");
            IWebElement e2 = d1.FindElement(By.Name("sa"));
            e2.Submit();
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can try locating getting the list of elements you want to iterate.

`ReadOnlyCollection<IwebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.tagname("a"));
foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
            {
                if (element.Text.equals("Searched text"));
                // Perform Acrion on 
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this syntax is correct but what about this?

```
IWebElement e3 = d1.FindElement(By.Link("4")); e3.Click();
```

Again not sure on the syntax but I hope you get the idea.  This is a very primitive method for doing this and it would only work if there is one link on the page that has the text "4".  But since this is a google search result its not going to be easy to automate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggession, but the issue here is that i want to automate it so that it can automatically search for the required element by navigating between the pages starting from page 1 and so on... Please throw some light on this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "automatically search for the required element by navigating between the pages starting from page 1 and so on".  Are you having trouble navigating with Selenium or do you need help with the algorithm that drives the selenium driver?  If your answer is algorithm its not clear what your end goal is.